# Find documents with arrays not containing a document with a particular field value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find all documents that do not contain at least one document with a specific field value.  For example here is a sample collection:

```
{  _id : 1,
  docs : [
        { foo : 1,
          bar : 2},
        { foo : 3,
          bar : 3}
         ]
},
{  _id : 2,
  docs : [
        { foo : 2,
          bar : 2},
        { foo : 3,
          bar : 3}
         ]
}
```

I want to find every record where there is not a document in the docs block that does not contain at least one record with foo = 1.  In the example above, only the second document should be returned.

I have tried the following, but it only tells me if there are any that don't match (which returns document 1.

```
db.collection.find({"docs": { $not: {$elemMatch: {foo: 1 } } } })
```

**UPDATE:** The query above actually does work. As many times happens, my data was wrong, not my code.

I have also looked at the [$nin operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/) but the examples only show when the array contains a list of primitive values, not an additional document.  When I've tried to do this with something like the following, it looks for the EXACT document rather than just the foo field I want.

```
db.collection.find({"docs": { $nin: {'foo':1 } } })
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this with the basic operators?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Using [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/#op._S_nin) will work, but you have the syntax wrong.  It should be:

```js
db.collection.find({'docs.foo': {$nin: [1]}})
```

Comment: Curious, why `$nin` instead of `$ne`? Couldn't you do `db.collection.find({'docs.foo': {$ne: 1}})`? (i.e. the same thing but no need for 1 to be in an array, as in [aedm's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38684656/3391108))

Comment: @tscizzle Yep, `$ne` is fine as well if there's only one value.

Comment: `$ne` also should be a little more efficient (quicker)

Answer (score 55):

Use the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator:

```
db.collection.find({'docs.foo': {$ne: 1}})
```

**Update:** I'd advise against using `$nin` in this case.

`{'docs.foo': {$ne: 1}}` takes all elements of `docs`, and for each of them it checks whether the `foo` field equals 1 or not. If it finds a match, it discards the document from the result list.

`{'docs.foo': {$nin: [1]}}` takes all elements of `docs`, and for each element it checks whether its `foo` field matches any of the members of the array `[1]`. This is a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), you compare an array to another array, each element to each element. Although MongoDB might be smart and optimize this query, I assume you only use `$nin` because "it has do to something with arrays". But if you understand what you do here, you'll realize `$nin` is superfluous, and has possibly subpar performance.

Comment: It's a cartesian product with an array with only one element : not sure performance hit is that high in that case. We would have to make a benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note the distinction between the possibilities as how you use `$elemMatch` can cause you to get the wrong results.

Not part of array documents **at all**:

```
db.collection.find({'docs.foo': {$ne: 1}})
db.collection.find({'docs': {$not: {$elemMatch: {foo: 1}}}})
db.collection.find({'docs.foo': {$nin: [1]}})
```

These are all equivalent albeit ordered in terms of preferred usage.

Not the **only** document in the array:

```
db.collection.find({'docs.foo': {$elemMatch: {foo: {$ne: 1}}}})
```

Took me a while to realize this is what I was doing wrong.