# Return MongoDB documents that don't contain specific inner array items

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose, mongodb-query

How can I return a set of documents, each not containing a specific item in an inner array?

My data scheme is:

Posts:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f91ec96241783dac1e16fe"), 
    "votedBy" : [
        {
            "userId" : "101",
            "vote": 1
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "202",
            "vote": 2
        }
    ], 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I want to return a set of posts, non of which contain a given userId in any of the votedBy array items.
The official documentation implies that this is possible:

[MongoDB documentation: Field with no specific array index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index)

Though it returns an empty set (for the more simple case of finding a document with a specific array item).
It seems like I have to know the index for a correct set of results, like:
votedBy.0.userId.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221599/find-documents-with-arrays-not-containing-a-document-with-a-particular-field-val) Question is the closest I found, with this solution (Applied on my scheme):

```
db.collection.find({"votedBy": { $not: {$elemMatch: {userId: 101 } } } })
```

It works fine if the only inner document in the array matches the one I wish not to return, but in the example case I specified above, the document returns, because it finds the userId=202 inner document.

Just to clarify: I want to return all the documents, that NONE of their votedBy array items have the given userId.

I also tried a simpler array, containing only the userId's as an array of Strings, but still, each of them receives an Id and the search process is just the same.

Another solution I tried is using a different collection for uservotes, and applying a lookup to perform a SQL-similar join, but it seems like there is an easier way.

I am using mongoose (node.js).

Answer (score 1):

User `$ne` on the embedded `userId`:

```
db.collection.find({'votedBy.userId': {$ne: '101'}})
```

It will filter all the documents with at least one element of `userId = "101"`

Comment: Hi @Tom, thanks for your reply. i'm afraid this doesn't work (Returns all documents). Let's look at a simpler example:
{'votedBy.userId': '101'} 
Shoud return only documents with an element 101, but returns no results at all.
The reason, in my opinion, is that it only works with 'votedBy.0.userId' for instance (Where we should iterate over all indexes), but in this combining-the-dots method it finds none.

Comment: @Bobcat100 It is working, I tested it on version 3.2 (don't know regarding older versions) so check that the schema is exactly as in the question and that you copied correctly. the example that you give and the query with `$ne` are not the same. the query: `{'votedBy.userId': '101'}` will return all documents with at least one element with `'101'` and the query in my answer will return documents where there is no element with `'101'`.

Comment: The example is indeed different, to show that in a simpler query the votedBy.userId doesn't work. I don't think I have a different version, for I am using the latest Azure documentDB, that should support this version.
Can you please check if my example:  {'votedBy.userId': '101'} returns the document containing 101, or a [] answer?
Thanks, Barak.

Comment: On your example schema, `{'votedBy.userId': '101'}` returns the document containing 101 and with my answer: `{'votedBy.userId': {$ne: '101'}}` it returns `[]` (no results). and this is what you wanted.