# Is there an opposite to mongoose populate() method? (Mongoose, node.js, express)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, routes

I have two mongoose schemes one for users and one for posts.

One user can like many posts.

At the end I would like to present in the client side all the posts the user liked in one section which I can do using the populate() method, and in another section the posts the user didn’t like without creating duplicates of the liked posts.

Is there unpopulate() method I can use to get only the unliked posts? If not, what is the best way to approach this?

```
userScheme = 
   { 
    // some other fields…

    post: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Post'
        }
  }


postScheme = 
   { 
     // some other fields…

     user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        likes: [
                {
                    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                }
        ],

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query for all the posts that doesn't have the particular user in their `likes` array i.e. is not liked the user yet. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221599/find-documents-with-arrays-not-containing-a-document-with-a-particular-field-val)

```
Post.find({ likes: { $nin: [user._id] }})
```